# Where does the guessed solution come from when solving DE systems with a double root?

Tags: systems-of-equations, roots

Say I have

$\vec{v}' = \begin{bmatrix}-2 &1\\-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}$

Solving this up to the characteristic equation, I get a double root $\lambda=-1$.

Assuming I didn't know any better, I'd move forward to find a solution

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}e^{-t}$

At this point, all the explanations I've found so far online have said "let's then try using the solution multiplied by t to see if that works" since that's the approach used when solving a 2nd-order equation. For this problem, it will fail. Then the explanation usually goes "Then, let's try

$$
\vec{v}=t\vec{n}e^{-t}+\vec{p}e^{-t}
$$

and everything works"; you end up with terms

$$
(A-\lambda I)\vec{n}=0 \\
(A-\lambda I)\vec{p}=\vec{n}
$$

and solve from there.

Let's say I just happened to know the first guess where the form of a solution is $\vec{v}=e^{\lambda t}p$. How would I then figure out from scratch that I could then add on $te^{\lambda t}\vec{n}$ to get everything to fall into place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is equivalent to $$x'=-2x+y$$

$$y'=-x$$

solving for $x$ provides $$x''+2x'+x=0$$ with characteristic root of $-1$ with multiplicity of $2$

One solution is $$x=e^{-t}$$

For the other solution we let $$x=u(t)e^{-t}$$ and solve for $u(t)$

Plug in  $$x''+2x'+x=0$$ and you come up with u(t)=t, hence the second solution is $$ x=te^{-t}$$ and the general solution $$ x=(C_1 + C_2 t) e^{-t}$$

We can find $y$ from $$y=x'+2x$$

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do this but fumbled when writing the problem in 2nd-order form. Now I'll try to repeat this in matrix form to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Might help to start with the scalar, 1D case.

Suppose $(\hat{D}-p)y=0$ where $\hat{D}=\frac{d}{dx}$.

Then a solution for $y$ is $y=Ce^{px}$.

Now let's start with $(\hat{D}-p)^2y=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-2p\frac{dy}{dx}+p^2y=0. $

This is also $(\hat{D}-p)[(\hat{D}-p)y]=0$.

Let's call $g(x)=[(\hat{D}-p)y]$.

From above, we know $(\hat{D}-p)g=0 \implies g=C_1e^{px}$

This implies the equation: $(\hat{D}-p)y=\frac{dy}{dx}-py=C_1e^{px}$

We can use integrating factors to get the following:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-py=C_1e^{px} \implies \frac{dy}{dx}e^{-px}-pye^{-px}=C_1=\frac{d(ye^{-px})}{dx}$$

Now integrate both sides and multiply by $e^{px}$:
$$y=(C_1x+C_0)e^{px}$$

We didn't get that additional x term from no where, it was necessary and not a guess. That some power of x is needed can be shown in the general case.

Suppose $(\hat{D}-p)^ny=\sum_qA_qx^qe^{px}$

Then $(\hat{D}-p)[(\hat{D}-p)]^{n-1}y=\sum_qA_qx^qe^{px}$

Let $g=[(\hat{D}-p)]^{n-1}$

Then
$$(\hat{D}-p)g=\sum_qA_qx^qe^{px}$$
$$\hat{D}(ge^{-px})=\sum_qA_qx^q$$
Then integrating:
$$ge^{-px}=\sum_qA_q\frac{x^{q+1}}{(q+1)}+C_0$$
$$[(\hat{D}-p)]^{n-1}=e^{px}(\sum_qA_q\frac{x^{q+1}}{(q+1)}+C_0)$$

It's conventional to combine the constant denominators and the constant coefficients together to get a new coefficient, often referred to with the same variable.

So a repeated root in the characteristic equation implies the solution is a linear combination of the product of all integer powers of x under the degree of the root of the characteristic equation and the general solution. The same principle applies to the case of vectors.

Comment: What's different in the system context as opposed to the scalar higher order context is that the "$t^k e^{\lambda t}$" type solutions don't point in the same direction, and this seems to be what the OP was trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It all can be recovered using Jordan Normal Form of the coefficient matrix. The trick is when $A = D + N$  where $DN=ND$  and $N$ is nilpotent, we can write
$$  e^{At} = e^{Dt}  e^{Nt}  $$
Here I meant $D$  diagonal, so exponentiating it is straightforward. Suppose we are in  dimension $n,$   we are guaranteed $N^{n+1} = 0.$  The we get  polynomial  entries (of $t$) in
$$  e^{Nt}  = I + N t + \frac{1}{2}  N^2 t^2 + \frac{1}{6}  N^3 t^3 + \cdots  + \frac{1}{n!}  N^n t^n. $$   Usually we have some smaller exponent as in $N^2 = 0$  or $N^3=0.$

**Practice:**

find $e^{At}$ where
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
7 & 1 \\
0 & 7
\end{array}
\right)
$$